# Loading XAML Resource File in ClassLibrary dll

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I have a WPF Application that contains a xaml file marked as ressource (buildprocess). During runtime I can load and access that file using following code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("some.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader reader = new System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader();
Border savedBorder = reader.LoadAsync(sri.Stream) as Border;
```

Moving the functionality and xaml file into a class library and mark "some.xaml" it as resource, the above code fails with IOException "The resource "some.xaml" could not be found". That sounds logically because I cannot successfully access `Application.GetResourceStream` inside a class library.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly
   .GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetManifestResourceStream("some.xaml") ;
```

returns `null`.

What is the correct way to Access such a file inside a dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resource name is incorrect.  Visual Studio creates the resource with the fully qualified name (e.g. the namespace and the resource name).

See [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Try something like:

```
 System.Reflection.Assembly
   .GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetManifestResourceStream("mycompany.myproduct.some.xaml");
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

I tried getting the full resource name by using 'this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();' 
The result is 'OWM.g.resources'. "OWM" is my root Namespace. Passing this value into 'GetManifestResourceStream' an UnmanagedMemoryStream is returned. Much larger than the expected filesize.

Comment: Is it twice than expected size?  If so its saved in UTF-16 not UTF-8.  But are you able to read it now?

Comment: No worries, if you like the answer then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggeled with full resource names.
This code solved the Problem:

```
Assembly assembly = GetExecutingAssembly(); 
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(this.GetType(), "some.xaml")) 
{ 
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream); 
   string Content = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
}
```

So there is no need to specify the full resource Name.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are right, but I have to notice one imprecision: the resource name should be in another format.

```
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("UCM.WFDesigner.Resources.Flows.DefaultFlow.xaml");
```

`UCM.WFDesigner` is my assembly name,
`Resources.Flows` is the folder name, 
and `DefaultFlow.xaml` is the xaml name.